# Marionette(Backbone) just render the new content when i modify the html content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette, erb

**Ruby on Rails/Backbone with Marionette app**

When i try to view the correct language changin it with i18n (i18n-js Ruby gem) i find that the content just change and add the correct language to the region when i add any manual change to a `layout-menu.jst.ejs.erb` template file.

This is what i have on menu-view.js.coffee

```
@CitaManager.module "Layout", (Layout, CitaManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  Layout.MenuView = Marionette.ItemView.extend
    template: JST["marionette/mine/templates/layout-menu"]
    ui:
      btnAgenda: ".btn_agenda"
      btnNotes:  ".btn_notes"
      btnVideoconference:  ".btn_videoconference"
      btnIndicators:  ".btn_indicators"
      btnVademecum:  ".btn_vademecum"
    triggers:
      "click @ui.btnAgenda": "menu:agenda"
      "click @ui.btnNotes" : "menu:notes"
      "click @ui.btnVideoconference" : "menu:videoconference"
      "click @ui.btnIndicators" : "menu:indicators"
    events:
      "click .btn": "btnClicked"
      "click @ui.btnVademecum": "openVademecum"
    initialize: (options)->
      @isPremium = options.isPremium
      @isStandard = options.isStandard

    btnClicked: (event) ->
      $('li', $(event.target).closest('ul')).removeClass('active');
      $(event.target).closest('li').addClass('active');

    openVademecum: ->
      if this.isPremium
        window.open('http://www.vademecum.es/registrase_connect?urlBack=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vademecum.es%2F', 'newwindow', 'width=400, height=400');
      else
        bootbox.alert('Lo sentimos, este servicio solo está disponible para los planes premium')
      return false

    onRender: ->
      console.log "Menu rendered"
```

I pasted on the template this

```
<p>
    <%= I18n.locale %>
</p>
```

i reload the page cause changes, then it says **es** (spanish) who is writen in code, and of course, you can view the texts on spanish, but if i change the language to "en" (english) it still showing **es** on the view but if i open the console and type now the same: I18n.locale it says "en"

Comment: Backbone doesn't offer two-way binding out of the box. You need another lib to do that, or you just need to re-render the view where there are changes.

Comment: thank you @EmileBergeron

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Problem was with filename `layout-menu.jst.ejs.erb` just remove `.erb` worked.